# eval() on a string, causes "SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing"

Tags: python, python-2.6

I am reading a text file line by line using a python program not written by me, and I found an error "SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing", which I narrowed down to `eval()` on a string of number.

The file looks like:

```
0,0.0,1,12,2,36,1
422189799,166217249.0,1,12,2,36,1
```

The code looks like:

```
istream = fopen(fin, 'r')
for line in istream.readlines():
    for v in line.replace('\n', '').split(','):
        print v
        eval(v)
```

The error looks like:

```
    eval(v)
  File "<string>", line 1
    1
    ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

which happens at the last field `1` of the first line.

I wonder what the problem is? Thanks.

Comment: What are you expecting to happen by eval-ing a sequence of numbers?

Comment: I guess eval() converts a string for a number to an appropriate number type. I didn't write the program.

Comment: Just remove that line. Because it doesn't store the result, it doesn't do anything except throw an error when it can't evaluate an expression.

Comment: This is very strange to say the least...

Comment: The usual culprit for mysterious behavior at end of line is a DOS carriage return.  See the [`bash` tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info) for some troubleshooting tips.

Comment: @tripleee you are probably correct, it ran fine for me with unix line endings, but after running unix2dos on the input file the error appeared.

Comment: you can try this `istream = open("fin.txt", "r")` instead of istream = fopen(fin, 'r').

Answer (score 1):

```
 > for v in line.replace('\n', '')...
```

To make code robust against different line ending conventions, you probably want

```
for v in line.rstrip('\r\n')...
```